# How to standardize the naming of photos in a folder in php?

Tags: php

I have a folder containing several photos all in .jpg
The name they should all have is `STYLE_COLOR-n.jpg` for example `K14700_7132-6.jpg` because I made a script that deletes all the photos greater than -6.jpg.

My problem is that I have photos that are badly renamed, i.e. they have an underscore at the end instead of the dash like :

```
K14700_7132_6.jpg
```

Some also have a dash on both like this:

```
K14700-7132_6.jpg
```

And so my delete script doesn't work if the pictures don't all have the same rename...

Is it possible to automatically replace all the dashes and underscores that are bad to have this format on all my folder `STYLE_COLOR-n.jpg`?

```
<?php

$dir = 'C:/wamp64/www/divers/photos/';

   $allFiles = scandir($dir);

   foreach($allFiles as $file) 
   {

        if (!in_array($file,array(".","..")))
      { 
  
        $file = $dir.$file;
        $filename = basename( $file ); //KA0710_7250-1.jpg

        $underscore = explode("_", $filename);
        // echo $underscore[0]."<br>";  //KA0710

        $endstring = end($underscore); 
        // echo $endstring."<br>"; //7250-1.jpg

        $underscore2 = explode("-", $endstring);
        // echo $underscore2[1]."<br>"; //1.jpg


          if ($underscore2[1] > 6)
            {
              unlink("$dir$filename");
              echo 'File ' . $filename . ' has been deleted'."<br>";
            }
          else
            {
              
            }                          
     }

  }

  echo "Deleted photos !";

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, this is the part you'll add to that code:

```
$parts = preg_split("/[-_]+/", $filename);
$newfilename = strtoupper($parts[0].'_'.$parts[1]).'-'.$parts[2];
if ($newfilename !== $filename) {
  rename($dir.$filename, $dir.$newfilename); // test this!
  $filename = $newfilename;
}
```

**Note** - this will permanently rename files (that need it) so BEFORE you run this in production, please test for the old/new rename arguments just to be safe!

Here is the whole enchilada

```
<?php
   $dir = 'C:/wamp64/www/divers/photos/';
   $allFiles = scandir($dir);
   foreach($allFiles as $file) {
    if (!in_array($file,array(".",".."))) { 
        $file = $dir.$file;
        $filename = basename( $file ); //KA0710_7250-1.jpg
        // first fix the format
        $parts = preg_split("/[-_]+/", $filename);
        $newfilename = strtoupper($parts[0].'_'.$parts[1]).'-'.$parts[2];
        if ($newfilename !== $filename) {
          rename($dir.$filename, $dir.$newfilename); // test this!
          $filename = $newfilename;
        }
        $underscore = explode("_", $filename);
        $endstring = end($underscore); 
        // echo $endstring."<br>"; //7250-1.jpg
        $underscore2 = explode("-", $endstring);
        // echo $underscore2[1]."<br>"; //1.jpg
        if ($underscore2[1] > 6) {
              unlink("$dir$filename");
              echo 'File ' . $filename . ' has been deleted'."<br>";
        } else {
              
        }                          
     }
  }
  echo "Deleted photos !";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your explanations! There is just one mistake, you have to put "rename($dir.$filename, $dir.$newfilename);" instead of "rename($dir.$file, $dir.$newfilename);"

Comment: Is it possible to add that all the names of the images, even those well named, are in upper case? with strtoupper no?

Comment: Yes, answer updated - `$newfilename = strtoupper($parts[0].'_'.$parts[1]).'-'.$parts[2];`